# Water well fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In my home village everyone has their own water well at the foot of the mountain (limestone) . The wells are over 100 feet deep but they are not cemented or have the area between the hole and the casing (PVC) sealed with bentonite or anything like it. Even though the well is 100+ feet deep, inside the well deep the water comes up to within 15 feet of the surface. I suppose the stone is fractured even though during the drilling they have reached meters and meters of solid limestone.

I assume that deeper wells are safer to drink /use and cleaner since the bad things (remains of cow manure, plain old dirt or septic waste) rarely reach say 100+ feet. However, since the casing is not sealed and the water inside the well reaches within 15-20 feet of the surface, is it safe to assume that that the water sometimes is as clean as it would be in a 15-20 feet well? The casing on top is solid, only the last few meters at the bottom of the well have it with holes for the water to come in.

Now the question is this: Suppose "dirt" leaches down from the surface, moves through cracks in stone and at 10 feet deep touches the PVC casing and....does it go down 100+ feet or does pressure stop it from doing so. What happens what the submersible pump (100+ feet down) turns on, does the water mix up and down?

Thanks guys,

Comment: Your question about cleanliness of the water is off-topic here (if you're concerned about it, you can get water filtration systems). As to your main question could you provide a diagram of what you mean? For example, how does the sub-pump connect into the piping?

Comment: I mentioned the cleanliness since that is the concern. For example, even if the water mixes a little bit it maybe enough to make all the water unusable. The sub-pump is near the bottom of the well and a hose runs from the pump to another hose that takes it to the deposit.

Comment: I understand your concern about dirty water, but that question isn't a physics question, so it's not on-topic here.

Comment: This is **not** a hygiene question. The question is if seepage into a well from 100+ feet deep can explain well water that goes up to 15 feet deep, or if the observed high water levels indicate there must be a leak higher up. It is very much physics.

Answer (score 1):

As posed there is no definite answer to your question.

It is certainly possible for water to enter the well at a depth of 100 feet, and have sufficient pressure that it eventually rises to within 15 feet of the top. That just means that the "water table" in that area is 15 feet below the surface.

If the sides of your well are reasonably well sealed so only water that had to seep through many feet of rock/soil enter the well, this will improve filtration - but it does not guarantee there is no mixing.

The physical principle here is that if you connect two vessels, and a steady state is allowed to be reached, then the water level in them will equalize:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The figure explains it a lot better and it makes sense. Also as the pump starts pumping and more and more water is needed it will all be mixed.  Now I'll use this to hopefully save someone from a trip to a hospital or worse :-) by telling them how to better seal their wells.  This question was both a hygiene and a physics questions, with physics deciding if there was need to worry. Some questions are just linked like this. thanks again